# Clarification on the Parametrizations of a Keyhole Contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the following contour on the complex plane

[image]

where there is branch cut on the negative real axis. What is the simplest parameterizations to solve the following contour integral
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{C_{R,\varepsilon}} w^{-z}e^{w}\,\textsf{d}w
$$
where $C_{R,\varepsilon} = \ell_1 + \kappa + \ell_2 + K$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ of principal value?

**EDIT:** I have attempted the following but not sure it would give a simple evaluation of the contour integral:

\begin{aligned}
 \ell_{1} &= \{w\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, w = xe^{-\pi i} + i\varepsilon e^{-i\phi},\, x \in [R,-\varepsilon\cos\phi)\} \\
 \kappa &= \{w\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, w = \varepsilon e^{\theta i},\, \theta \in [-\phi,\phi)\} \\
 \ell_{2} &= \{w\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, w = xe^{\pi i} + i\varepsilon e^{i\phi},\, x \in [-\varepsilon\cos\phi,R)\} \\
 K &= \{w\in \mathbb{C}\,:\, w = R e^{-\theta i},\, \theta \in [-\phi_{K},\phi_{K})\}
\end{aligned}
where $\phi_{K} = \text{Arg}(Re^{\pi i} + i\varepsilon e^{i\phi})$.

Comment: To clarify, you just want the formula for the parametrization?

Comment: @CSquared, Yes, but if you could show the evaluation it would still be okay.

Comment: I think it is misguided to insist upon explicit parametrizations, and evaluations of the fragmentary integrals. We'd just make ourselves crazy with needless details/baggage. Rather, estimates of errors toward limiting values are essential...

Comment: @paulgarrett, I'm informed regarding this point you are making. Can you please provide some details on your approach as an answer?

Comment: @venrey, yes, in the near future... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think my main advice here would be to *not* get embroiled in formulaic details of the parametrization (and limit). Much as in proofs of continuity, we do not actually need the *best* delta for a given epsilon, and so on.

Plus, the *idea* of the thing gives a good guide to what details to ignore. :)

So, first, the *idea* is that the whole integral is $0$ because there are no poles inside it...

Second, the integral over the large almost-circle and small almost-circle should go to $0$, not because of any cancellation (which would be toooo subtle), but, rather, just based on absolute-value estimates.

Then what is left would be the (limit of) the "incoming" and "outgoing" integrals... along the negative real axis. Because we've had to "slit" the plane to make a well-defined fractional power function, the limits as we approach from above, and from below, differ not only by a sign (due to opposite directions of integration), but also by a $e^{2\pi i z}$.

Perhaps with this qualitative advice you can finish it yourself. :)